# Dynamically adding the text view in android

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I am new to android
I have table layout which contains a single table row.. This row has got two text views in the first and second column respectively..

Can anyone tell me how to add these two text views present inside the table row dynamically ??

Answer (score 1):

provided you've set content view to layout with TableRow:

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
TableRow tr = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.<your table row id>);

//apply layout params to your TextViews, set text etc...

tr.addView(tv1);
tr.addView(tv2);
```

Comment: I am setting the content view to the relative layout .. this relative layout contains table layout inside it .. I am getting error for tr.addView(tv1)... any help on this ??

Comment: Which error are you getting? Post part of your code where you are adding textViews and your xml layout

Comment: this is my back end                                                          TableRow tr =(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.trId);
  
  tournameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tourname);
  tournameText.setText(tourResponse.getTourname());
  
  dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
  
  dateText.setText(tourResponse.getFormattedDate());
  tr.addView(tournameText);
  tr.addView(dateText);

Comment: are dateText and tournameText(R.id.tourname) on your layout?